# Prettier code formatter inconsistency when formatting html code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I've been running into this issue there the Prettier code formatter isn't formatting my HTML code consistently in VS Code as seen below. I expect it to format both of the `<input>` tags the same but for some reason, it splits each attribute of the second `<input>` into separate lines.

[image: Prettier issue]

Any particular reason why this is happening, if so how can I fix it so that it's consistent with the formatting of the first `<input>` tag?

Comment: You should look into how to use CSS and HTML then you don't need to use `<br>` for stuff like new rows. Use HTML `<label>` to connect a label to an input (you don't do that currently). With CSS you can align and space Elements. Use `<br>` only in Texts where you need to force a line-break.

Answer (score 1):

this happens because it has line length limit which is by default 80.
you can search <Prettier: Print Width> in VS Code settings and change its value.